# Strong parameters issue with custom controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using [`acts_as_taggable_on`](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) plugin in conjunction with my `User` model.

```
acts_as_taggable_on :skills
```

Now, I have a custom controller called `SkillsController` to add skills via ajax.

```
class SkillController < ApplicationController
  def add
    current_user.skill_list.add(params[:skill])
    current_user.save # Not saving!
  end
end
```

and in `routes.rb`

```
get 'skill/:skill', to: 'skill#add'
```

I guess it has to do something with Strong Parameters, but I don't know how to solve it as it stands.

The `current_user.save` isn't working, how to solve it.

P.S `current_user.errors` shows `@message` is "too short" as per my validations. But how do I just save the `skill_list` without having to modify other attributes or running validations on them?

Comment: you are passing `params[:tag]` while the param name is `params[:skill]`

Comment: @MoustafaSallam that was a typo..sorry. I've `:skill` in the code.

Comment: I don't think it is a Strong parameter issue, strong parameter works with mass assignment. I think the problem with the methods chaining `skill_list.add` can you please show both methods

Comment: @MoustafaSallam those aren't my methods. Please have a look at the link https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on, which I've also put in my question. You could get some pointers from there.

Comment: What errors does `current_user` have?

Comment: @japed there's no error. Just that `current_user.save` is returning `false` and hence the record isn't updating

Comment: Yes, but it will return false because of validation errors more than likely.  So `current_user.errors` will be more than one.

Comment: @japed oh that one. Sorry a noob in rails here. Just tried and got password is too short. So I guess it's running validations of all the attributes, when I don't actually need it.

Comment: use "current_user.save(:validate => false)", if you don't want validation check  in your case

Comment: @GauravGupta yeah! That was it. Please put up an answer

Comment: @japed thanks mate +1 on one of your helpful answers. Your comment helped me resolve this one. <off_topic> By the way do you know of any gem that helps in doing what twitter does with "1 new tweet" or facebook does with "New stories"?</off_topic>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save current_user without validation check you can do just like as:

```
current_user.save(:validate => false)
```

This will work for you :)